# Python regex group not returning full group

Tags: python, regex

```
regexlord = re.compile(r'([a-z])+(0)+(\d)+')
yomyomnumber = regexlord.search('spam003')
print (yomyomnumber.group(1))
print (yomyomnumber.group(2))
print (yomyomnumber.group(3))
```

So I've got a string in the form of spam003 and I want to be able to change the number at the end (the 3). Thus, I want to use regex and call the specific groups. However, when I call the groups, group 1 prints only (m), group 2 prints only (0), and group 3 only prints (3). Because this is greedy matching, I'm expecting that group 1 prints (spam), group 2 prints (00), and group 3 prints (3). I'm stumped on why this isn't happening.

Comment: Move the + signs inside the parens where you want multiple characters to be returned (e.g. `r'([a-z]+)(0+)(\d+)'`), and you'll get exactly what you expect.

Comment: @jedwards Please don't answer in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for the help! It works out now.

Comment: @jedwards [Comments aren't for answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). I recommend you spend your time answering the question in the dedicated "answer" section that SO provides for that exact purpose

Comment: @jedwards Given that the same mistake was made in all three places, I think this could be considered real confusion about capture groups. Moreover, if you don't think this is a real question then you have even less license to answer it.

Comment: @Challenger5. I did. (Though you may not have sufficient rep to see that, I'm not sure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first set of parentheses will only capture the first instance of each character. You need to move the `+` sign to inside the parentheses to capture every character matched by the `+`.

```
([a-z]+)(0+)(\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change this line:

```
regexlord = re.compile(r'([a-z])+(0)+(\d)+')
```

to this:

```
regexlord = re.compile(r'([a-z]+)(0+)(\d)')
```

it should be work:)